# Увеличивает ли нагрузку большой размер моделей в Unity3d

Tags: unity3d, 3d

*(Возможно глупый вопрос)*

Увеличивает ли нагрузку большой размер моделей в Unity3d?
Допустим,что у нас есть два куба и другой в 10 раз больше первого.По логике,куб который больше в 10 раз должен больше нагружать устройство на котором есть игра,но тогда почему сами игры не делают миниатюрными в редакторе?(или делают ,но я не знал об этом?)

Comment: Я не эксперт в этой предметной области. Однако, скажу следующее : большой куб будет больше нагружать систему только тогда, когда полигонов будет больше и/или текстура будет больше. Ну и, наверно, будет увеличена нагрузка в сравнении с первым кубом, если второй будет огромным, как игровой мир, и постоянно будет взаимодействовать с игровыми объектами (тени, физика и пр)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размер не имеет никакова значения. Если сравнивать 2 объекта, одинаковые по количеству полигонов и материалу, то маленький может быть затратнее просто потому, что он прямо перед камерой и занимает больше место в фрейме, и соответственно больше пикселей и дольше его рендеринг, а большой так далеко что отображается как один пиксел.